# SVN - How to make files revision in consistence in /trunk and /tag folder?

Tags: svn

I have a .NET project,and using VisualSVN Server and tortoiseSVN Client.
Sometime when i finish a task, and i ensure that is stable enought to production use,i will do the follow :

1.open the repo-browser , delete all the files in /trunk.
2.Import the latest copy to /trunk from my local project.
3.switch to /tag ,create a folder name with datetime (e.g. 2011.03.30), and import the latest copy from my local project again.

however, the files in /tag ,the revision is newer then /trunk.
But both set files is same.

So my question is, how to make them consistence?

Or my step is wrong?

As i know /trunk is current version, even stable or in-development.
/tag is for stable build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @Keith wrote, you need to understand revision numbers in SVN: they are sort of like a counter of changes made *to the entire repository*. There are version control systems like CVS which operate on the file level and there it's possible to have the version numbers of files in sync between branches, but in SVN you create a *copy* in order to create a branch. That is a modification of the repository and thus you get a new revision.

If you do not delete and recreate but instead use normal SVN copies then you don't need to know any revision numbers at all since you can see in the SVN log of the corresponding files when and where they where "branched" from.

Answer (score 3):

Your steps are all wrong. You should branch the trunk, then check out a new workspace from the branch. make your edits and commit to the branch. At some later point you merge your branch back into trunk.

Comment: So, is it mean "/branch" is the working copy, "/trunk"  is use for merge the latest version from "/branch", and "/tag" is use for stable build?

Comment: @SilverNight: Keith is not exactly responding to your scenario - he is talking about branching and re-merging.

Comment: @silver Usually. @Doc I answered the second question. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just don't delete /trunk when making a production release (why do you think that's necessary, you are loosing your per-file history?). Commit your current work to the repo (trunk), create a new tag folder (datetime, if you like), and use `svn copy` to copy the last trunk revision to the tag folder. For example, here is the essential line from the tag script I am using:

```
svn copy %SVNREPOSITORY%/ProjectFolder/trunk %SVNREPOSITORY%/ProjectFolder/tags/%NEWTAG% -m"Version %NEWTAG%"
```

If you want to make sure /trunk does not contain any unneeded files, delete them at the time there are not needed any more in the repo, not later.

Comment: Thanks you @Keith,@DarkDust,@Doc Brown. now, i understand much more.If i can mark more then one as answer, i will make all.